# Golang SHA512 Not Matching OpenSSL SHA512

Tags: go, openssl, sha

I am attempting to generate a SHA512 hash of a string in bash and then verify that SHA512 hash in golang.  However, I cannot figure out the exact combination of utilities/flags to get the same hash produced in both places.

Bash code:

```
echo "hello sha world" | openssl dgst -sha512 -hex
9c5b761a9bf8f74da84c57101669b8042b860ca5871a15c4e729758ad1dee58d562ddf8fa303ada1f3e0278fdff4af9a72f57ce0514be98f6a959daabda926f5
```

Golang code:

```
s := sha512.New()
s.Write([]byte(`hello sha world`))
fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(s.Sum(nil)))

d13fa494d2609a6f67e906de96d92788bd8ab46dec0f5e48d8cdb8c540628a752aa135262aa5804dcc907e261abe4472faf01fc13eb97e4e8c85e5c0438f2acb
```

I have also tried a base64 encoding of the binary representation without any luck:

Bash:

```
echo "hello sha world"  | openssl dgst -sha512 | openssl base64 -A
OWM1Yjc2MWE5YmY4Zjc0ZGE4NGM1NzEwMTY2OWI4MDQyYjg2MGNhNTg3MWExNWM0ZTcyOTc1OGFkMWRlZTU4ZDU2MmRkZjhmYTMwM2FkYTFmM2UwMjc4ZmRmZjRhZjlhNzJmNTdjZTA1MTRiZTk4ZjZhOTU5ZGFhYmRhOTI2ZjUK
```

Golang:

```
s := sha512.New()
s.Write([]byte(`hello sha world`))
fmt.Println(base64.RawStdEncoding.EncodeToString(s.Sum(nil)))

0T+klNJgmm9n6QbeltkniL2KtG3sD15I2M24xUBiinUqoTUmKqWATcyQfiYavkRy+vAfwT65fk6MheXAQ48qyw
```

Any help would be appreciated on how I can get Golang to generate the same hash as openssl.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `echo` command also sends a newline character, so your first example calculates the SHA-512 checksum of the string `"hello sha world\n"`.

If you use the same in Go, you get the same output:

```
s := sha512.New()
s.Write([]byte("hello sha world\n"))
fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(s.Sum(nil)))
```

Or simply:

```
fmt.Printf("%x\n", sha512.Sum512([]byte("hello sha world\n")))
```

These output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2cz0p2InRne)):

`9c5b761a9bf8f74da84c57101669b8042b860ca5871a15c4e729758ad1dee58d562ddf8fa303ada1f3e0278fdff4af9a72f57ce0514be98f6a959daabda926f5`

If you want to calculate the SHA-512 checkout of some text in bash without a trailing newline character, use the `-n` param of `echo` like this:

```
echo -n "hello sha world" | openssl dgst -sha512 -hex
```

This outputs the same as your original Go code:

`d13fa494d2609a6f67e906de96d92788bd8ab46dec0f5e48d8cdb8c540628a752aa135262aa5804dcc907e261abe4472faf01fc13eb97e4e8c85e5c0438f2acb`